# Did any of Metagaming Concepts' board games make it to the PC?

Tags: gaming-history

I loved [Metagaming Concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metagaming_Concepts)' board games like *Ogre* and *WarpWar* and always thought that they could have been made into PC games.

Did any of Metagaming Concepts' board games make it to the PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Metagaming Concepts went out of business and Steve Jackson founded Steve Jackson Games, there eventually was a release of **Ogre** for the computer in 1986 as published by ORIGIN Systems, Inc. Here's a page of [release info from Moby Games](http://www.mobygames.com/game/ogre/release-info), and there's [tangential mention at Wikipedia under Spin-Offs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogre_(game)). It seems to be the only one that made it to any electronic format.